# How to remove queryParms after redirect?

Tags: angular

```
  returnToPreviousPage(){
         this.router.navigate([this.returnUrl], { queryParams: { customerId: this.caId } });
    }
```

I have this method so what i want is when user return to previous page, to clear queryParams. Any suggestion how can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

Use a ternary :

```
  returnToPreviousPage(){
         this.router.navigate([this.returnUrl], { queryParams: yourBoolean ? { customerId: this.caId } : null });
    }
```

Where `yourBoolean` can be any condition

**UPDATE**

```
  returnToPreviousPage(){
         this.router.navigate([this.returnUrl], yourBoolean ? { queryParams: { customerId: this.caId } } : null);
    }
```

Comment: It wil not clear params after redirect it will only send customerId depend on boolean. I need to send that params always but after that to remove it

Comment: No it will empty your queryParams. But see my update if you want to not send any queryParams at all.

Comment: Because you didn't handle the null option in your component where you redirect.

Comment: How will i handle null option in component where i redirect?

Comment: I guess it's your in your `ngOnInit()` ? Then simply `ngOnInit() { if (this.yourStateServiceThatGetParams.queryParams) {/* do things */} else {/* do other things */}`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147130/discussion-between-none-and-trichetriche).